# Storybook inlineStories works but breaks the props interactions

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, storybook

I have a popup media gallery component and I need to use it inline, to document it in the storybook. when I add the code below in '.storybook/preview.js'

```
export const parameters = {

  docs: {
    inlineStories: false,
  }
}
```

It works as I expected, but when When I set inlineStories: false, there is no problem in modifying properties on Canvas, but in Docs, the modification does not take effect.

To avoid this error I tried to add inlineStories: false to the popup component only, but when I do that, inline mode stopped working too.